# Boundary and Interior of set $\{-3,2,5\}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to see if I'm correctly understanding and applying the definition for interior and boundary points.

Interior point:

> A point x in R is an interior point of S if there exists a neighborhood N of $x$ such that $N \subseteq S$.

Boundary point:

> ... if every neighborhood of $x$ contains at least one point in $S$ and at least one point not in $S$, then $x$ is a boundary point.

Given the set $\{-3,2,5\}$ I assume the only interior point is $2$ since this is not an interval and there is no neighborhood at $-3$ and $5$.

Additionally, I don't think there is any boundary points or accumulation points, again because there is no neighborhood.

Is this correct?

Comment: @ZacharySelk updated my question with the definitions

Comment: Then all three points are boundary points.

Comment: @ZacharySelk how is that possible?

Comment: Metric space $X$ is not specified here; from answers, I guess it is $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boundary is the full set; there is no interior point.

Note that there is no open interval that contains $2$ that is conatained in your set. Same for the other points in the set (or in fact  any real). Thus the interior is empty.

And every open interval containing one of the points, will also contain a point not in the set. So every point in the set is a boundary point.

Moreover there are no other boundary points and indeed there is no accumulation point.

Comment: OK, I understand now why there are no interior points.  $-3,2,5$ are just elements, not intervals.  But I don't understand the justification why they are all boundary points.  Can you explain it another way?

Comment: Informally, a point $x$ is a boundary point of $S$ if an element from $S$ and an elements not in $S$ are arbitrarily close to $x$. Formally If you take an element from $S$  for $x$, say $x=2$, then of course some element from $S$ is arbitraily close to $2$, namely $2$ itself!. And you also find an element not in $S$ arbitrily close. More formally let us show $2$ is a boudnary point. We need to show for every $\epsilon > 0$, the interval $(2 - \epsilon, 2 +\epsilon)$ contains an element from $S$ and an element not from $S$.

Comment: For the element from $S$, we take $2$ and for the element not from $S$ we take $2 + \epsilon/2$  (except for the strange corner case when $\epsilon = 6$ where we take $2+\epsilon/3$ or avoid to select $5$ in some other way).

Comment: Note that none of these points is an accumulation point, since in that case we need an element from $S$ different from the element itself close by. And we cannot find that.